# Create your root folder called "gtk-hello"

Tags: development, folder, root

I am learning to code following the instructions on the elementary website.
It said Create your root folder called "gtk-hello"
My question is how do I Create this?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Jeff

Comment: I know how to create a folder , just not a root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a regular folder. From the coding tutorial perspective, it will become the root folder. All following components and code will be filled in that folder.

Comment: thanks for your info